# Organising divs on different screen sizes with bootstrap 3 grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three divs that i need to position based on screensize. Im using bootstrap's grid system on my page, but i have encountered a small issue with the placement

Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: let me know if any more details are needed.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="div1" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-8"><h2>Some header text here DIV1</h2></div>
<div id="div2" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-2"><span>Some span here DIV2</span></div>
<div id="div3" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-md-2"><span>Some other span here DIV3</span></div></div>
```

The fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2n1pcnn9/2/)

And an image of how i want it to work:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the layout and order you want, you'll need to use nesting along with `push` `pull` like this..

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="div2" class="col-xs-7">div2</div>
            <div id="div3" class="col-xs-5">div3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="div1" class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-xs-12">div1</div>
</div>
```

I used col units `col-7` and `col-5` for div's 2 and 3 (based on your picture) but you may need to change those to the actual units you want for those columns.

Demo: http://bootply.com/jFfCKhkuR3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `column ordering`, see the bootstrap docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Using `col-xs-push-12` in div1 and pull consequently the other two divs.

Here you have a [small snippet](http://www.bootply.com/77853#) showing the effect of the col push and pull

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2n1pcnn9/16/ is this what you ment? cant get it to work properly, the div only moves further to out of the screen insted of moving top